# When using a wand to cast a concentration spell, does the user need to make a saving throw to maintain concentration when damaged?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, concentration

Say that a creature uses a magic wand to cast a spell (e.g. Entangle). If the user is hit, do they need to make a Con saving throw to maintain concentration on the spell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Concentration is concentration it doesn't matter if you cast the spell from an item or if you cast the spell from a spell slot.

DMG p141

> The spell uses its normal casting time, range, and duration, and the
>   user of the item must concentrate if the spell requires concentration.

PHB p203 indicates the rules on when concentration can be broken which include: taking damage, casting another spell (regardless of source) that requires concentration and being killed or incapacitated.

All this said there is a notable exception. Certain sentient items can  actually cast a spell themselves and maintain the concentration freeing the wielder from doing so. Blackrazor is an example of that.

Answer (score -2):

For the specific item 'Wand of Entangle,' yes.  In general, it depends, as wands are not described as either 'cast from the item,' like a scroll, or 'bypass the casting of a spell,' like a potion.

DMG P141

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item.  The
>   spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any
>   of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, unless the
>   item's description says otherwise.  The spell uses its normal casting
>   time, range, and duration, and the user of the item must concentrate
>   if the spell requires concentration.  Many items, such as potions,
>   bypass the casting of a spell and confer the spell's effects, with
>   their usual duration.

Most but not all wands include in their description "to cast."  Those that do not would fall under the bypass catagory.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say with this answer. You seem to duplicate the other answer, but then provide an opinion at the end that's counter without any support.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, can you explain how wands don't fit under "cast from the item" rulings? That seems the exact category they are under. Moreover, you don't seem to actually answer the question here.

Comment: DMG 140  "Wand: A magic wand is about 15 inches long and crafted of metal, bone, or wood.  It is tipped with metal, crystal, stone or some other material."  Wands have no useful definition in their description.  Edited to make the answer clear.

Comment: @DMDeath can you give an example of a wand you claim doesn't count as casting?

Comment: Also you really need to edit in the actual answer to the question, because right now your answer still doesn't come out and say it.

Comment: @ rubiksmoose  The wand of Paralysis is an example of a wand that does not use the 'to cast (spell)'. DMG 211 "While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges to cause a thin blue ray to streak from the tip tword a creature you can see"

Comment: @DMDeath Yup if there's no spell, there's no concentration so it doesn't matter for this question. Only wands that cast concentration spells are relevant to this Q.

Comment: @rubiksmoose I was only responding to your specific question, so I looked up a quick example.  If you want an example of a wand that does not count as casting, and involves a concentration spell, look at 'Wand of Wonder' on DMG 212.  It does not use the words 'to cast', but you choose a target and roll a die;  on 50-53 for example “You enlarge the target as if you had cast enlarge/reduce.  If the target can't be affected by that spell, or if you didn't target a creature, you become the target.”  Enlarge is a concentration spell.

Comment: @DMDeath Good example! Though, in that case, I would argue they are not casting a spell at all, just causing an effect *as if* they had cast it so concentration might still be needed. Though that is less clear. It might be worth exploring that a bit in your answer.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Possibly grounds for a good question, but given that other effects do say "cast", I think you're right in that it's not a spell, but just an effect and using the spell description as guidance for how it works.